# Set the value of an input element to that of a variable

Tags: jquery, click, field, hidden

I have this jQuery script for populating my hidden field:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $("#myHiddenField").val(4);
    $("#form").submit(); 
});
```

I would like to replace the hard-coded "4" with a variable:

I tried this:

```
$("#button").click(function(i) { 
    $("#myHiddenField").val(i); 
    $("#form").submit(); 
});
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to pass the parameter `i`. What is the issue with this section of code?

I have 4 different buttons. I don't want to create 4 function click for each button. In this case `i` is the value of a hidden field to identify which button has been clicked.

Comment: In your code `i` is event object.

Comment: where does `i` come from?

Comment: What value do you want to send? Where do you want to get it from? What do you expect "i" to have in your example?

Comment: i dont know what he thinks "i" is,but it will be event handler in this  case.

Comment: show HTML code we can help more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attribute to store temporary value and access it later:

```
// set value
$("#button").attr("temp", 4);
...
$("#button").click(function() { 
        $("#myHiddenField").val($(this).attr("temp")); 
        $("#form").submit(); 
});
```

You can also use a global variable but it is not recommended.

Comment: So if I have 4 button I can add an attr to the button and use it to make the trick... Right ?

Comment: yes, you can also use .data() instead of attr() for complex data

Comment: I recommend using the pre-defined, customizable "data-xyz" attribute approach, since those attributes are valid, while invalid ones (like "temp") will be discarded by JS compilers (like ReactJS) -- if anyone plans on using this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `i` to the value, then:

```
var i
$("#button").click(function() { 
        i=$("#myHiddenField").val(); 
        $("#form").submit(); 
});
```

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns the value of the element by default.

If you want to set the value to `i`, then you need to set `i` first:

```
var i=4
$("#button").click(function() { 
        $("#myHiddenField").val(i); 
        $("#form").submit(); 
});
```

---

In your current code, `i` is sent to the `Event` that was generated by the click. I don't think you want to do that.

Comment: This will not get or set the variable `i`. In this case, the parameter passed to the `.click` function is a jQuery object not a custom variable. This will either a) overwrite the jQuery object with the value from `#myHiddenField` or b) set the value of `#myHiddenField` to the jQuery object. For more information, visit the [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function documentation page.

Comment: @War10ck: oops. I copied the code from the OPs question, and completely forgot to remove the `i` from the arglist. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to the `click` event handler is a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/), not a custom variable. What you want to do is simple:

```
var someVariable = 4;
$("#button").click(function() { 
    $("#myHiddenField").val( someVariable ); 
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

Just be sure `someVariable` is defined in the parent scope when you bind your click handler or in the global scope (or within the handler itself, depending on where the value originates).

Answer (score 0):

`i` in your case is `event`... so it won't be able to put the value in hidden field...define a variable i inside click or a global variable ... 
try this

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
    var i="somevalue"; //value u want
    $("#myHiddenField").val(i); 
    $("#form").submit(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you want to get the value from. What gets passed into the anonymous function is the event object, not a normal variable. Try this instead:

```
$("#button").click(function(event) {

    var x = getValueFromSomewhere();

    $("#myHiddenField").val(x);
    $("#form").submit(); 
});
```

Or this:

```
var y = getValueFromSomewhere();

$("#button").click(function(event) {

    // The anonymous function can access variables from the outer scope.
    $("#myHiddenField").val(y);
    $("#form").submit(); 
});
```